# Cloud Run Set IAM Policy Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to set up an IAM Policy to a Cloud Run service using Python but I can find how to add the policy and binding fields. I'm trying:

```
from google.cloud import run_v2
from google.iam.v1 import iam_policy_pb2  # type: ignore

def sample_set_iam_policy():
    # Create a client
    client = run_v2.ServicesClient()

    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = iam_policy_pb2.SetIamPolicyRequest(
        resource="RESOURCE_NAME",
        policy=[
            bindings=[
                {
                    "role": "roles/run.invoker",
                    "members": [
                        ]
                    },
                ],
            ],
        version=2,
    )

    # Make the request
    response = client.set_iam_policy(request=request)

    # Handle the response
    print(response)
```

Currently the IAM Policy looks like this:

```
version: 1
etag: "\007\005\325\344%V\223^"
bindings {
  role: "roles/run.invoker"
  members: "allUsers"
```

I want to take out the `allUsers` member from the binding.

I looked [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/run/latest/google.cloud.run_v2.services.services.ServicesClient#google_cloud_run_v2_services_services_ServicesClient_set_iam_policy) but I can't understand how to add this fields.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you set the policy binding, you don't add or remove one binding. So, if you want to remove only allUsers from the bindings, you have to get the binding, remove the user by iterating on the answer, and submit the updated object to set the new binding.

You can't remove the binding only, you set the WHOLE policy everytime.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I can’t seem to make work is the policy itself. I can’t find an example on how binding, role, members, etc need to be set for the request.

Comment: Do you have an error?

Comment: File "/home/lj/setIAMPolicy.py", line 11
    policy={
    ^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?

Comment: It's a python dict definition issue

Comment: Yes, I know. That's the thing I don't know how to use the policy field within the request.